# Meaningful method name which create a resource when the one is not exist

Tags: naming-conventions

I'm searching for an alternative name for a method which create a resource when the one is not exist. Previously I used long names like "createAddressWhenNotExist" or "createAccountIfNotExist".

What do you think about "ensureAddress" or "ensureAccount"?  If you find this name in code will you understand it?

Comment: Why not check if the address exists on the caller side and then call *createAddress*?

Comment: I would like to keep client side as simple as possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the naming method/ function is not fully represent the actual process.

You must declare the function description in that function with comment.

And I think `createAddrIfNotExist` or `createAccountIfNotExist` are the good names.

Comment: Thanks for share your opinion. What do you think about `ensureAddress` or `ensureAccount`? Does it make sense to you ?

Comment: It sounds great man.